# Confused with how to compare 1 int with 3 others and declare one less than the other three

Tags: c

I am trying to implement a code that seems easy, but I keep missing the point. The problem I am having is I am trying to take my budget and compare it to my prices for items (p's ..). If there is ONLY ONE item that is less than my budget, then I want it to print that. If there is more than one item, I want it to print that there is more than one item. This will be entered in by the user, so lets say they enter the following numbers for the price of item's, 40, 110, 200. I want the if statement to say there is only one item under budget, but if the 40 was 120, have it print NO Item is eligible with my budget. This is what I have gotten:

```
int p1, p2, p3, budget;
p1 = 40;
p2 = 110;
p3 = 200;
budget = 100;

    if((budget>p1 || bugdget>p2 || budget>p3) && (budget<p1+p2 || budget<p1+p3 || buget<p2+p3))
        {
            printf("\n(3) Only one of the is less than or equal to your budget.");
        }
    else
        {
            printf("\n(3) More than one of the items are cheaper than your budget or the items are all more expensive.");

        }
```

Again, I want it to output the correct statement. If only one int is less than budget then I want it to output that only one is less than budget otherwise it should output the else statement above.

Comment: I would just count the number of items that are under the budget.

Comment: Are you looking for how many items individually are under budget, or combined? E.g., if `p2` were 70, would that be 2, because both `p1` and `p2` are both under 100, or only 1, because `p1+p2` exceed budget?

Comment: Correct, if p2 were 70, I would want it to printf the else statement, otherwise if only one (p) item is below the budget, I want it to say Only one of the items is less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a count of how many items individually fall within budget, I would suggest putting the items in an array, and using a loop to check. E.g.,

```
int checkItems(int budget, int* items, int itemCount)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<itemCount; ++i)
    {
        if (items[i] <= budget)
           ++count;
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    //populate your array of items
    int items[3] = { 40, 110, 120 };
    int count = 0;
    count = checkItems(100, items, 3);
    if (count == 1)
        printf("\n(3) Only one of the is less than or equal to your budget.");
    else
        printf("\n(3) More than one of the items are cheaper than your budget or the items are all more expensive.");
}
```

However, if you're looking to see if multiple items added together fit under budget, then you're looking at a [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Edit:

A non-array version:

```
int main()
{
    int p1 = 40, p2 = 110, p3 = 200;
    int budget = 100;
    int count = 0;

    if (p1 <= budget) ++count;
    if (p2 <= budget) ++count;
    if (p3 <= budget) ++count;

    if (count == 1) .... as above
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. One question, is there a long way to do this or is this the only way? I am sure it is the simplest, but I like to learn about my options.

Comment: Well, you could have a separate `if` statement for each `p#`, and increment a counter if it is under budget, and then check the counter as above.

Comment: What would that look like?

Answer (score 1):

> If there is ONLY ONE item that is less than my budget, then I want it to print that.

Add the compares and switch on that sum.

```
//if((budget>p1 || bugdget>p2 || budget>p3) && (budget<p1+p2 || budget<p1+p3 || buget<p2+p3))

switch ((p1<budget) + (p2<budget) + (p3<budget)) {
  case 1:  printf("\n(3) Only one of the is less than or equal to your budget."); break;
  case 0:  printf("\nNO Item is eligible."); break;
  default: printf("\n(3) More than one of the items are cheaper than your budget ....");
}
```

---

Edge: OP's goal's is "less than my budget".  I would expect "less or equal to my budget".